# Approving Azure pipeline using API

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-devops-rest-api

I'm working on an azure DevOps pipeline. I have an approval stage which stops the pipeline until someone approves the run so the pipeline resumes.

Is there a way, to approve the run with a REST API call? Or is there maybe a way to stop and resume a pipeline using a REST API call without an approval?

(PS. Its a yaml pipeline)

Comment: it's yaml pipeline?

Comment: Yes, it is.
My Bad I forgot to mention

Comment: Automating the approval is not really how approvals are supposed to work. If you don't want the pipeline to be interrupted, then maybe you should just omit the approval stage?

Comment: I don't want to automate the approval process. I want to "outsource" it. I'm working on a slack bot that send the approval to a slack channel so the members of the channel can then just press a button of the slack bot's message to approve the pipeline.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [Approvals Rest API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/approvalsandchecks/approvals?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1).

First, get the approvals list with [Approvals - Query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/approvalsandchecks/approvals/query?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1) and find your approval id.

Second, approve it with [Approvals - Update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/approvalsandchecks/approvals/update?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1), in the body use the `approvalId` you got from the previous step:

```
[
  {
    "approvalId": "approvalId from the Approvals - Query step",
    "comment": "Approving",
    "status": "approved"
  }
]
```

Comment: Can you add a full rest api uri how you are able to query for all approval ids? And do you know by chance how to query for approval configuration?

Comment: I have attempted this, getting the approval ID without issue, however when I attempt the PATCH call to approve the stage, I receive the error:

{"$id":"1","innerException":null,"message":"Value cannot be null.\r\nParameter name: updateParameters","typeName":"System.ArgumentNullException, mscorlib","typeKey":"ArgumentNullException","errorCode":0,"eventId":0}

I cannot find any information on this in the documentation, the body I send in the PATCH is
[{
        "status":  "approved",
        "approvalId":  "e23aa595-7745-4015-9fdd-be7863faeda1",
        "comment":  "Auto approval"
 }]