# Approving pipeline stage azure devops via API

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api, azure-pipelines-yaml

I am trying to approve stages of a multi-stage yaml pipeline in azure devops but my REST requests to the endpoint detailed [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/approvalsandchecks/approvals/update?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1&tabs=HTTP) return an error

```
{"$id":"1","innerException":null,"message":"Value cannot be null.\r\nParameter name: updateParameters","typeName":"System.ArgumentNullException, mscorlib","typeKey":"ArgumentNullException","errorCode":0,"eventId":0}
```

I followed the strategy of obtaining the approval ID from the timeline of the pipeline ([documented here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/timeline/get?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1)), then getting the approval details ([documented here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/approvalsandchecks/approvals/get?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1&tabs=HTTP)), which gave me the 2 objects:

Approval stage from timeline

```
{
"previousAttempts":  [

                     ],
"id":  "e23aa595-7745-4015-9fdd-be7863faeda1",
"parentId":  "4ae2b754-452d-5a7c-1d05-4887a615523a",
"type":  "Checkpoint.Approval",
"name":  "Checkpoint.Approval",
"startTime":  "2023-11-15T12:36:50.5633333Z",
"finishTime":  null,
"currentOperation":  null,
"percentComplete":  null,
"state":  "inProgress",
"result":  null,
"resultCode":  null,
"changeId":  71,
"lastModified":  "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
"workerName":  null,
"details":  null,
"errorCount":  0,
"warningCount":  0,
"url":  null,
"log":  null,
"task":  null,
"attempt":  1,
"identifier":  "e23aa595-7745-4015-9fdd-be7863faeda1"
}
```

and approval direct from GET request

```
{
"id":  "e23aa595-7745-4015-9fdd-be7863faeda1",
"steps":  [

          ],
"status":  "pending",
"createdOn":  "2023-11-15T12:36:50.53Z",
"lastModifiedOn":  "2023-11-15T12:36:50.531529Z",
"executionOrder":  "anyOrder",
"minRequiredApprovers":  1,
"blockedApprovers":  [

                     ],
"_links":  {
               "self":  {
                            "href":  "https://dev.azure.com/<orgName>/8f6c8014-5c15-49aa-8efc-adb274f30be3/_apis/pipelines/approvals/e23aa595-7745-4015-9fdd-be7863faeda1"
                        }
           },
"pipeline":  {
                 "owner":  {
                               "_links":  "@{web=; self=}",
                               "id":  23633,
                               "name":  "20231115.7"
                           },
                 "id":  "64",
                 "name":  "Traveller"
             }
}
```

I then constructed the PATCH body

```
[
{
    "status":  "approved",
    "approvalId":  "e23aa595-7745-4015-9fdd-be7863faeda1",
    "comment":  ""
}
]
```

and sent this to the endpoint

```
https://dev.azure.com/<orgName>/<projectname>/_apis/pipelines/approvals?api-version=7.1-preview.
```

All documentation and other questions on this subject suggest I am doing this correctly, yet I cannot get past this error.

Other SO question consulted include
[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71237839/approving-azure-pipeline-using-api) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60133259/azure-pipelines-bulk-approve-of-deployments-to-environments)

Comment: Interestingly. I called the same `PATCH` API request within POSTMAN it worked as expected. May I know which command tool/language you used to send the request? Have you tried with other methods like `Invoke-RestMethod` in PowerShell to reproduce the same error?

Comment: @AlvinZhao I am using powershell, my code is as follows: `$body =  @( @{        "approvalId"= $_.id        "comment" = ""        "status" = "approved"    })    
        Write-Host (ConvertTo-Json $body)
    $uri = https://dev.azure.com/org/proj/_apis/pipelines/approvals?api-version=7.1-preview.1"
        $response = Invoke-RestMethod -Method PATCH -Uri  $uri -Headers $headers  -Body ($body | ConvertTo-Json ) -ContentType "application/json" `

Comment: @AlvinZhao based on your suggestion, I have tried using insomnia (a similar rest client to postman) to send the request and that succeeded with the same body and headers.  I will now investigate the differences in the raw request using a proxy like fiddler.  Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can reproduce the same issue.

[image]

The cause of the issue is that the format: `$body | ConvertTo-Json` will not add the [] in the request body.

[image]

To solve this issue, you can change to use the following format: `ConvertTo-Json $body`

```
$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Method PATCH -Uri  $uri -Headers $headers  -Body ( ConvertTo-Json $body  ) -ContentType "application/json"
```

Then it will pass the correct request body to the Request.

Answer (score 0):

I used the json contents directly to define the request body. Here is my sample for your reference.

```
$organization = "Org"
$project = "Project"
$MyPat = 'xxxxx'
$B64Pat = [Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes(":$MyPat"))
$URL = "https://dev.azure.com/$organization/$project/_apis/pipelines/approvals?api-version=7.1-preview.1"
$header = @{
'Authorization' = 'Basic ' + $B64Pat
'Content-Type' = 'application/json'
}
$body = @"
[
{
    "status": "approved",
    "approvalId": "2c8f92ed-6c78-4ccb-8cb6-59afec19cec2",
    "comment": ""

}
]
"@

$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Method PATCH -Uri $URL -Headers $header -Body $body | ConvertTo-Json
```